# inputstream returning correct message while debugging, but not while running directly

Tags: android, bluetooth, usb-debugging

I am working on a bluetooth application which receives data from some device.
When I am using 'Debug' option from Android studio and debugs through the application, I get proper response, but as soon as I remove breakpoints the messages are received incomplete, and my application crashes.

Any possible solutions...?

I am reading the input stream as follows :

```
bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
mHandler.obtainMessage(1, begin, bytes, buffer).sendToTarget();
```

Comment: how are you reading from the InputStream?

Comment: bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
mHandler.obtainMessage(1, begin, bytes, buffer).sendToTarget();